# CGAL: Arrangement with Exact_circular_kernel_2

Tags: cgal

I am trying to build an Arrangement of Circles using the `Exact_circular_kernel_2`. When I insert a Circle into the Arrangement, I get a segmentation fault.
This is my code:

```
CGAL::Circle_2< CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2 > circle1( CGAL::Point_2< CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2 >(1,1), 2 );
CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2::Circle_2 circle2 = circle1;
CGAL::Circular_arc_2< CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2 > arc( circle2 );
CGAL::Arr_circular_line_arc_traits_2< CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2 >::Curve_2 curve = arc;
CGAL::Arrangement_2< CGAL::Arr_circular_line_arc_traits_2< CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2 > > myArrangement;
cout<<curve<<endl;
cout<<myArrangement.is_valid()<<endl;
insert ( myArrangement, curve );
cout<<"done"<<endl;
```

The Code compiles without warnings and it doesn't matter whether I use `circle1` or `circle2` in line 3, the result is the same.

The program prints the following before the segmentation fault happens:

> 1/1 1/1 2/1 1 0 1/1 -1/1 2/1 1 1/1  0 1/1 -1/1 2/1 1 1/1
>   1

So the values of values of `myArrangement` and `curve` seem to be valid.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I am aware that I could use another Kernel, but I want to compare performances of different Kernels, so not using this Kernel wouldn't really be a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem.

Below is a slightly more clean version, but your version works on my platform as well, Ubuntu 12.04, g++ 4.6.3, CGAL 4.1 (or at least close to 4.1), What is yours?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Exact_circular_kernel_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_circular_line_arc_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Arrangement_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_circular_kernel_2                           Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                         Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Circle_2                                        Circle_2;
typedef CGAL::Arr_circular_line_arc_traits_2<Kernel>            Traits;
typedef Traits::Curve_2                                         Curve_2;
typedef CGAL::Arrangement_2<Traits>                             Arrangement;
int main()
{
  Circle_2 circle(Point_2(1,1), 2);
  Curve_2 curve(circle);
  Arrangement arr;
  std::cout << curve << std::endl;
  std::cout << arr.is_valid() << std::endl;
  CGAL::insert(arr, curve);
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, g++ 4.6.2, and like you "CGAL 4.1 (or at least close to 4.1)". I'm not sure how to determine the version either.
I couldn't compile your version, it says in line 15 there's `no matching function for call to ‘boost::variant...`.
I've also tried g++ 4.7.2, but nothing changed.

So I installed a Ubuntu 12.10 with g++ 4.6.3 and CGAL 4.1, and on this platform, both source code versions compile and work without any problems.